# How I want to connect db with vs?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

```
string paramID = Request.Params["idParam"] != null ? Request.Params["idParam"] : "";
        if (paramID != "G0007")
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT a1.ID, a2.asset_cat, a2.asset_type, a2.wo_no, a2.asset_no, a2.cks_zone, a2.cks_model,a2.cks_date,a2.cks_time," +
                        "a2.name_srv, a2.name_chk, a2.name_vfy, a2.design_srv, a2.design_chk, a2.design_vfy, a2.time_srv, a2.time_chk, a2.time_vfy, a2.date_chk, a2.date_srv, a2.date_vfy," +
                        " a3.status_T, a3.remarks, a3.RTUID " +
                        "FROM tbl_checklist a1 " +
                        "LEFT JOIN tbl_checklist_data a2 ON a2.IDChecklist_data= a1.ID " +
                        "LEFT JOIN tbl_SasRTU a3 ON a3.RTUID=a3.RTUID " +
                        "WHERE a1.ID ='" + paramID + "G0007";
```

Comment: Can you share the details about question by editing it?

Comment: You're using both MySQL and SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Mashitah, you posted this question 3 days ago, so potentially, by now, responding is a moot point.

I believe no one responded to your question because your question is not well formed and the example does not further the question’s clarity.

If your question is: how can you connect to a database from within c# code in order to run the query stored in the string sql, as in your code above; and the parameter stored in the string paramID along with its if statement are irrelevant, then:

You need a connection string to connect to your database of choice.  You tagged both SQL Server n MySQL.  Try the site: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ for the appropriate connection string.

A word of caution.  Be mindful of the fact that the connection string carries your password, as such either store the password or the whole connection string away from your code and source code repository.  One possibility for storage of the password/connection string is an environment variable or even an encrypted version of that password/connection string within the environment variable.

For a more comprehensive example of connection to a database see: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/823854/how-to-connect-sql-database-to-your-csharp-program

If I missed the intent of your question then please clarify.